# Inesplicable OpenGl shader behaviour on macOSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl, glfw

I create the vertex array, i create the shaders, compile and link them, but when i use drawarrays nothing happens.

No geometry is drawn on screen while i should see a red triangle.
No error in the command line no problem at all but the triangle won't appear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace std;

static GLuint compileShader(const string& source,GLuint type);
static int createShader(const string& vertexShader, const string& fragment);

int main(void){

    // I INITIALISE GLFW TO HAVE THE LATEST VERSION OF THE SHADER VERSION
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


    //I CREATE THE WINDOW
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"Dio suino",NULL,NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental= GL_TRUE;

    //I INITIALISE GLEW
    if(glewInit()!=GLEW_OK){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }

    //I SPECIFY THE VERTEX DATA
    float bufferData[6]={
        0.5,-0.5,
        -0.5,-0.5,
        0.0,0.5
    };

    GLuint bufferId;

    // I CREATE THE BUFFER, BIND IT AND SPECIFY ALL THE INFO NEEDED
    glGenBuffers(1,&bufferId);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,6*sizeof(float),bufferData,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,2*sizeof(float),0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    // I CREATE THE VERTEX AND FRAGMENT SHADERS
    string vs,fs;

    vs = 
    "#version 330 core \n"
    "in vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\n";

    fs =
    "#version 330 core \n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    color = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

    //I USE THE PROGRAM
    int shaderProgram = createShader(vs,fs);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);


    // WINDOW LOOP: CLEAR COLOR, SWAP BUFFER ECC
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){


        glClearColor(0,60,80,0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3); 

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();


    }

    cout<< glGetString(GL_VERSION)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

//CREATES THE SHADER PROGRAM WITH ALL THE SHADERS LINKED
static int createShader(const string& vertexShader, const string& fragment)
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint vs = compileShader(vertexShader,GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fs = compileShader(fragment,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glAttachShader(program,vs);
    glAttachShader(program,fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

//COMPILES THE SHADER
static GLuint compileShader(const string& source,GLuint type)
{
    GLuint id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id,1,&src,nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int debug;
    glGetShaderiv(id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&debug);

    if(debug == GL_FALSE){

        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&length);
        char message[length];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id,length,&length,message);
        fprintf(stderr,"Something went wrong in the shader of type %i: %s",type,message);
        glDeleteShader(id);
    }

    return id;
}
```

Now these are the libraries that i have included.
The makefile:

```
CC = clang++
MAIN = main.cpp
LIB = -lglew -lglfw 
FWORK = -framework OpenGl
NAME = -o dio -std=c++11

all:
    ${CC} ${MAIN} ${LIB} ${FWORK} ${NAME}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The only thing that jumps out to me is that your vertex shader specifies `in vec4 position` when the point values you’re supplying are 2 floats, i.e. `vec2`. Does changing that (and then updating the later line to `gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0)` make it work?

Comment: vec4(position,0.0,1.0) gives compile error. Did you mean vec4(position.xy,0.0,1.0) ?
with that it compiles but still no triangle :'(

Comment: No, I mean changing `in vec4 position` to `in vec2 position` *and* changing `gl_Position = position` as above.

Comment: Nothing. still no triangle and no compile error...

Comment: Where's your [VAO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)?  They aren't optional in Core contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a core profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context), then you have to create an named [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), because the default VAO (0) is not valid. The VAO states the specification of the vertex arrays.

You can switch to a compatibility profile context, to solve the issue, if it is supported by your hardware and driver (probably not on macOSX):

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object:

<s>`glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);`</s>

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

But, I recommend to create a Vertex Array Object, before the specification of the generic vertex array data. The VAO has to be bound, when [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) and [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml) are called, because this instruction change the state vector of the VAO:

```cpp
GLuint bufferId;
glGenBuffers(1,&bufferId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,6*sizeof(float),bufferData,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,2*sizeof(float),0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Comment: by switching to COMPAT the programs yields seg fault. Now i will try adding the vao.  
Is the vao a recent thing? the tutorial i'm following is only three years old, but it doesn't use the vao, nor it needs to use the window hints to make the shaders compile.

Comment: i had to switch back to core profile, but after adding the VAO it works!!! Thank you so much!! Can you explain in layman's words what is the vao doing exactly?  
How is this vertex array related to the buffer i previously created? i just create and bind it but what does it actually do to make things work?

Comment: @Adonai I recommend to read [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). In short words, the VAO stores all the specifications which necessary to draw a mehs. It doesn't store the vertex data (data is stored in the [VBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)) but it stores a reference to the VBO and all what is specified by `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray`. In compatibility profile there is the default VAO (0), which is initialized at startup, but that is not valid in core.

Comment: @Adonai Thank you. You're welcome. Note, the compatibility profile doesn't seem to be supported by your hardware and OpenGL driver (it works fine for me).